# Regex in django models

Tags: python, regex, django, django-models

I've got a problem with regex in django models, the file name must start with letter or numer and the rest of work can caontains letters, numbers and two special signs: - and _. My code looks like:

```
file_validator = validators.RegexValidator(
regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*$',
message=(u'Name must start from letter or number, it can contains big and small letters, numbers and special signs: - _'),
code='invalid_file',
)
```

But when I test it in my project, when I write file name: "mike", there is an error message. What I do wrong?

Comment: You forgot to mention what the error message is

Comment: `the file name must start with letter or numer` -> you have to use + instaed of *  `'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$'`

Comment: Actually, `r'^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w-]*$'` is enough.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not need the `+` as [Avinash suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385914/regex-in-django-models#comment66098698_39385914), you just need to drop the first `*` quantifier that means *zero or more occurrences*. Since it allows 0 occurrences the *must start with letter or number* rule does not work.

Use

```
r'^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w-]*$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL2oW2/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - 1 occurrence of an ASCII letter or digit
- `[\w-]*` - 0+ digits, letters, `_` or `-` sybmols up to
- `$` - the end of string.

Note that `\w` matches ASCII letters and digits in this case since `re.UNICODE` flag is not used.

Also note that `-` at the end of the character class does not have to be escaped, **but** if you plan to add more chars to the class later, it is a good idea to keep it escaped.